# aplicar propriedade css diretamente por javascript e uma boa pratica?

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou criando um site e para eu poder manter um controle maior e economizar tempo de ter que ficar trocando de aba toda hora eu estou aplicando as propriedades direto pelo javascript, gostaria de saber isso influencia alguma coisa `insira o código aqui`
    $("#teste").css("border-style","solid").css("background-color","transparent")
    .css("height","100%");

```
$("h1").css("display", "inline-block");

$("#teste1").css("background-color","blue")
.css("height","50px");

$("#teste2").css("background-color","green")
.css("height","50px");

$(".navbar-header").css("background-color","transparent")
```

Comment: Vai dificultar a manutenção da tua aplicação, além de atribuir uma responsabilidade para o JavaScript que não é do Javascript. Usar uma coisa para algo que ela não foi projetada é a melhor definição de "gambiarra"

Comment: Como foi dita acima, a manutenção será problemática. Quando você precisar fazer alguns ajustes furutamente, verá a força do `Ctrl+Tab`.

Comment: Não existe isso de boa/má prática, esse termo foi inventado há alguns anos em TI como maneira de desconversar quando vc não sabe explicar algo, mas quer dar a impressão que sabe do assunto, principalmente com quem não é da área ou não tem experiência. O fato é que usar JS para coisa que não precisa é sempre problemático. Você tem processamento desnecessário, inconsistência dependendo do tipo de proxy/firewall que encontrar pelo caminho, e está usando a camada errada para a tarefa. Se for coisa dinamica, é justificável fazer em situações pontuais, mas só se não tiver um jeito nativo mais óbvio.

Comment: Poderia colocar na pergunta ([edit]) alguns exemplos de como está aplicando o javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Aplicar propriedades, como `background-color` não é uma boa prática, fica ruim de rastrear e entender os estilos que você está usando, agora se você aplicar classes, ai fica bem melhor.

Isso inclusive é bem facilitado no `javascript` usando `classList.add` ([w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)), ou mesmo com `jQuery` usando `addClass`, `removeClass` ou `toggleClass` ([api.jquery.com/toggleclass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)).